# store database multiple records into variables using a DataReader

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datareader

I'm trying to retrieve and store 14 database records into variables using a DataReader(). I know how to store multiple fields into variables, but I don't know how to store 14 records with one column. I'm using MS Access and VB.

```
Try
    con.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read
        variableName = dr.Item("Description")
        Now, how can I do it for the other 13 variables?????
    End While
    con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    con.Close()
    MsgBox(ex.Message) : Exit Sub
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try, is create a List variable, and then using a for each look, cycle through each data row, and add the column to the list variable. The code is not exact but should be enough information to get you along.

```
Dim lst as new List(of String)

    Try
        con.Open()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read
         For Each rw as datarow in dr.Rows()
            lst.add(rw.item("Description"))
          Next
        End While
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.Message) : Exit Sub
    End Try
```

Comment: thanks Austin, but I think "Rows()" is not part of a Data Reader.